Drools upgrade from 6.5.0 to 7.0.0
We are facing one issue of race condition and it has been fixed in version 7.0.0 (as per this https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-1135)
To fix, we want to update to 7.0.0 at minimum and currently we are using 6.4.0.Final as below
parent-project\pom.xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>knowledge-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.drools.knowledgeapi}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

child-project\pom.xml
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

To upgrade to drools 7.0.0, Do we need to upgrade the knowledge-api version as well (to 6.5.0 the latest available)? As we will be updating drools-decision tables, drools-core, drools-compiler to 7.0.0
Really appreciate the response or any pointers.
Tried
We tried with updating all version to 7.0.0 except knowledge-api( which we kept as 6.4.0) but it's throwing exception as,
Failed to instantiate [org.drools.runtime.StatelessKnowledgeSession]: Factory method 'stateMapppingKnowledgeSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/compiler/builder/impl/KnowledgeBuilderImpl
